# Using safe SSL ciphers with OpenSSL

Tags: openssl, encryption

Given [this site](http://safecurves.cr.yp.to/) dedicated to choosing safe ciphers for encryption purposes, can someone please tell me what to do (ie how to choose and specify ciphers) to make my OpenSSL-based app as safe as possible?

The app needs to work with as many browsers as possible (hmmm, IE7+?)

Comment: What do you mean by as safe as possible? what are you trying to protect?

Comment: In SSL, client and server negotiates cipher algorithms.

Comment: Please specify "as safe as possible". I.e., "not coding your app would prevent anyone from intercepting its communications, since there's nothing to intercept" would currently fit your definition.

Answer (score 1):

See here for a decent list of ciphers to enable: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17463708/1121879

Long story short:

Hashing:

- SHA+ good
- MD5 + anything = bad

Encryption:

- AES128+ = good
- EC = mostly good

Other:

- *DH* = really good (usually means enabling of PFS)

Comment: Any chance you can describe how to enable and disable those in code?  What I fear is screwing that bit up and ending up with broken security without knowing it.

Comment: http://www.skytale.net/blog/archives/22-SSL-cipher-setting.html describes how to do most of that