# Azure SSL EV optimizing

Tags: ssl, azure-web-app-service, ocsp

I currently am using an SSL certificate on my website, but using the online SSLCheck from GlobalSign I noticed that it could use some optimizing.
For the hosting I use an Azure WebSites environment and I have no idea how I can change the options given. I can't find anything on the internet how to setup these settings.

The link is here:
https://sslcheck.globalsign.com/en/sslcheck

The list of options that need optimizing:

- Server does not have session resumption enabled
- Server has not enabled HTTP Strict-Transport-Security
- Server does not have OCSP stapling configured
- Server doesn’t prefer ciphers that enable forward secrecy.
- Server uses RC4 cipher with modern browsers

Thank you in advance for supporting me with this issue.

Comment: These options can probably be changed in a startup task via IIS settings or registry changes. Have you looked at how to accomplish your goals on IIS? Be aware that you might have to touch the registry, restart services and possibly even the whole WebRole.

Comment: I did find some possible solutions based on IIS itself, but I cannot change the registry. I may have said the wrong Azure service. I have edited just now. I don't use WebRoles but Websites!

Comment: Websites does not seem to offer any detailed SSL settings at the moment. There are some questions [similar to your request](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20450631/468244).

Comment: Thank you for your comment @SimonOpelt. Is there nothing possible by using the Powershell as far as you know?

Comment: Take a look at [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22313430/468244) to see if that helps you.