# How to configure Forward Secrecy in Azure (Web Roles and Worker Roles)

Tags: azure, azure-web-roles, azure-worker-roles

How can I configure [Forward Secrecy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward_secrecy) in Azure (Web Roles and Worker Roles)

Comment: In order to get an answer you have to better describe the scenario you are trying to achieve. How the question is currently structured doesn't show any details.

Comment: There are no proper answers yet but this is a duplicate of [that question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20450631/468244).

Comment: Take a look at [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22313430/468244) to see if that works for you.